# How to hide text in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I would like to share a Google Docs to other people but certain sections in the document are not complete, so I would like to hide them such that when they view or even edit the document they cannot see the sections.

Creating a copy of the entire document is cumbersome so that is not what I'm after.

This is possible from within Google Docs?

Comment: Currently there is an option to protect range which you have not finished by going to Tools -> Protect Range &sheet.You should select the range which you need to protect and then set the permission

Comment: Sorry, but that does not apply. Note in title of the question I said "Google document", not "Google spreadsheet".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Short Answer

At this time Google documents do not have a way to hide content.

## Alternatives

An alternative is to publish to the web the document before you start to work in the sections that want to hide.

Another alternative is create a copy of the document and remove the content to share, then share the copy instead of the original.

## References

[Docs editors Help](http://support.google.com/docs)

Answer (score 3):

You can effectively hide text by moving it to another document, then inserting a link in the original document.

For example, you want to hide the details of the deprecated version, but still make them available if desired.

```
    Deprecated version of product:
      text to be hidden
    Current version of product:
      ipso lorem ...
```

Move the "text to be hidden" to a new Google Doc. Back in the original file, highlight the "Deprecated..." line, from the menu choose Insert->Link and select the new Google Doc.  You have now created a hyperlink to the "hidden" text.  It's not ideal from a workflow point of view; but at least it works pretty well.

Ideally an add-on could be written that pops up the hyperlinked text when you hover over the link.  A nice little project; maybe I'll do it when I find the time.

Answer (score 2):

Change the highlight color to match the text color then change it back when you want to see

Answer (score 1):

You may have a Google Docs document that you will be issuing to end users as a PDF.  You can put hidden text, for example a Version Control section, in a Comment. It will not be copied to the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

If your use case more "hide this non-useful thing so it doesn't take up so much space" and less "hide this because I don't want other people to see it", you could potentially:

Make the font size 1 for whichever sections you want to "hide", which reduces the space it takes up down to a fraction of what it was.